# Address of the Pointer pointing to the first element

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

In http://www.fredosaurus.com/notes-cpp/arrayptr/array-diagrams.html website, it states that

> Pointers hold the memory address of other data and are represented by a black disk with an arrow pointing to the data it references.

For example,

```
int a[5];  // Allocates memory for 5 ints.
. . .
a[0] = 1;
for (int i=1; i<5; i++) {
a[i] = a[i-1] * 2;
}
```

would result in.
[image]

My question is how can I print the address of the pointer pointing to the array?
I know that `&a` or `&a[0]` gives us the address of the first element. But how can I access the pointer pointing the array?

Comment: That's not how an array is laid out in memory. There is no separate pointer called `a`.

Comment: "But how can I access the pointer pointing the array?" There isn't one unless you make one. I agree, the diagram is confusing/wrong...

Comment: That page you linked to is wrong. Don't read it, forget you saw it, get [a good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: There are no pointers in the above code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

An array and a pointer are not the same thing.  What the memory really looks like is this:

```
   a
-------
|  1  |  a[0]
-------
|  2  |  a[1]
-------
|  4  |  a[2]
-------
|  8  |  a[3]
-------
| 16  |  a[4]
-------
```

So if you were to print `a` and `&a`, you would see that they print the same value.

Answer (score 1):

If the array is on the stack as it would be in your example code then the image below is a more accurate representation of how the memory would be laid out. I've also added an additional pointer to hopefully add some clarification.

```
int a[5];
a[0] = 1;
for (int i=1; i<5; i++)
    a[i] = a[i-1] * 2;

int* b = a;
```

[image]

It may be easier to think of the `[]` notation of defining an array as a little syntactic sugar. When calling functions and passing in `a` the function will be called with the address of `a[0]` being passed in.

When passing `b` to a function it's the value that will be passed in, which is the address of `a`.

Answer (score 0):

You can have lots of pointers pointing to `a[0]`.

Just as for a pointer to the array, create a pointer variable pointing to `a[0]` and then take a pointer to it. You will have one pointer to one pointer pointing to the array.

Answer (score 0):

> I know that `&a` or `&a[0]` gives us the address of the first element.

Technically. `&a` is in fact the address of the array itself. It just has the same value as address of the first element. But note that the type of the expression is different. `&a` is a `int (*)[5]` (pointer to an array of 5 integers), while `&a[0]` is a `int*` (pointer to an integer).

> My question is how can I print the address of the pointer pointing to the array?

First step is to have a pointer. You don't have any pointer variables in your example. An array is not a pointer. The sentence *"The actual array variable, a in this example, is a pointer to the memory for all of its elements."* of the page is very misleading, as an array is not a pointer object. The drawn diagram is not correct for the program.

Here is a program that is correct according to the diagram:

```
int array[5];   // Allocates memory for 5 ints.
int* a = array; // a pointer to the first element of the array
a[0] = 1;
for (int i=1; i<5; i++) {
    a[i] = a[i-1] * 2;
}
```

Here we actually have a pointer. Now you can print the address of the pointer:

```
std::cout << &a;
```